# Java merge list from database with list from excel

Tags: java, algorithm, list, join, merge

I would like to merge two lists of objects in Java. One is a list of objects from a database and the second list is from Excel.

1. The first list of objects contains data like:
   `[name(str),valid_from(date),valid_to(date),active(flag)]`
   Objects are equal if names, active flags are equal and dates of obj1,obj2 - valid_from,valid_to are disjoint intervals.
   There can be two elements on the list with overlapping date intervals and the same name only if active flag is not equal.
2. The second list of objects contains the same data and also information about whether to update, remove or create new record on the first list:
   `[name(str),valid_from(date),valid_to(date),active(flag), action_type(c/u/d)]`

//edit: my code is:

```
public class ClassA {
    private String name;
    private Date validFrom;
    private Date validTo;
    private boolean active;

    public ClassA(String name, Date validFrom, Date validTo, boolean active) {
        this.name = name;
        this.validFrom = validFrom;
        this.validTo = validTo;
        this.active = active;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Date getValidFrom() {
        return validFrom;
    }

    public Date getValidTo() {
        return validTo;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<ClassA> objectsFromDB = getObjectsFromDB();
    List<ClassB> objectsFromFile = getObjectsFromFile();

    Map<String, ClassA> objectNameToClassA = buildObjectNameToClassAMap(objectsFromDB);

    List<ClassA> objectsToCreate = new ArrayList<ClassA>();
    List<ClassA> objectsToUpdate = new ArrayList<ClassA>();
    List<ClassA> objectsToDelete = new ArrayList<ClassA>();

    for(ClassB object: objects) {
         ActionType actionType = object.getActionType();
         if(ActionType.CREATE.equals(actionType) {
             objectsToCreate.add(object.getObjectA());
         }
         if(ActionType.UPDATE.equals(actionType) {
             objectsToUpdate.add(object.getObjectA());
         }
         if(ActionType.DELETE.equals(actionType) {
             objectsToDelete.add(object.getObjectA());
         }
    }


}

    private static Map<String, ClassA> buildObjectNameToClassAMap(List<ClassA> objects) {
        Map<String, ClassA> result = new LinkedHashMap<String, ClassA>();
        for(ClassA object: objects) {
           result.put(object.getName(), object);
        }
        return result;
    }

}

enum ActionType {
    CREATE, UPDATE, DELETE;
}

class ClassB {
    private ClassA classA;
    private ActionType actionType;
    public ClassB(ClassA classA, ActionType actionType) {
        this.classA = classA;
        this.actionType = actionType;
    }

    public ClassA getClassA() {
         return classA;
    }

    public ActionType getActionType() {
        return actionType;
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly are the types of your objects? Are they both `String`s?

Comment: The datatypes are not strings, but objects ClassA has fields: String,Date Valid From, Date Valid To, boolean active and ClassB has the same fields plus Enum action type that has options [C(reate new)/U(pdate)/D(elete). My solution is to assume that objects in database are in correct format and then: 1. build Map - Map<ClassA.getObjectName(), ClassAInstance>

Answer (score 0):

I would first define a class for your objects where you override the equals method in order to respect your conditions of equality. Then I would use one of the classes of java.util that implement the Set interface, HashSet for example. Then use the add method on this set with your objects. In set arithmetics, adding is a set union and so it performs a merge.

Comment: I will try to modify my solution to use HashSet instead of map and I have already implemented the equals method. Thanks, maybe this will help...